# Mobile Screen Highlight/Tooltip Overlay - Feedback Loop

Tags: mobile-application, accessibility, tooltips, overlay, examples

## Context

I'm working on a mobile app that provides real-time feedback on accessibility issues of other applications (not built or controlled by me) on the device, similar to [Axe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deque.axe.android) or [Google's Accessibility Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.auditor). It can call out several different issues, but to call out a specific one: [poor text-to-background color-contrast](https://webaim.org/articles/contrast). The way the app works is it records the entire screen and checks for issues as the user continues using the device, navigating through screens in the app they want to test. It identifies the bounding box of the issues and highlights what areas of the screen have an issue using an overlay that draws on top of the app under test. This behavior is similar to the way Facebook's chat bubbles work on Android, except it doesn't capture any input.

Example of issue highlighting: 
[image]

## Problem

I have struggled to figure out how to provide meaningful feedback to the user, indicating what the issue is and where it is on the screen without cluttering the UI or causing the feedback to affect the results as it re-scans the screen. This issue has been worked around by similar apps by only supporting a screenshot mode where you analyze a single snapshot of an app and use the screenshot as a basis for marking up the issues. I am trying to move away from that mode as I find it too restricting for my goal of realtime feedback, so I consider it a non-option.

So far I've tried

1. Highlighting content with an issue.

   **Problems**

   1. Color-contrast detection is broken if you are changing the color of the UI with the highlight.
   2. It also isn't clear what each highlight represents, forcing users to memorize what each color highlight represents
2. Adding a border around the issues and adding a tooltip with the issue type in a corner.

   **Problems**

   1. If the tooltip is inside the bounds, it can

      1. be too big to fit in a small box
      2. cover up the text such that the [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) changes the bounds of the box, causing it to resize every frame as the text bounds adjust to the tooltip.
   2. If the tooltip is outside the bounds, it can overlap with too much of the rest of the content and make it very difficult to use the app underneath all the tooltips.
   3. Either way, the bounding boxes frequently get picked up as letters (usually "i" or "l" at the beginning or end of the words, causing the boxes to gradually extend outwards every frame as wraps around each additional "l" from the previous frame. I've tried changing the border to different styles, but found dots can get turned into "*" and dashes turn into "_" or "-" at the top and bottom.

      This gives you an idea of how the border expands as the text it recognizes morphs due to the border

   ```
          ----    ------    --------
    hi -> |hi| -> | hi | -> |  hi  |
          ----    ------    --------
   "hi"  "lhil"  "l hi l"  "l  hi  l"
   ```
3. Just providing borders in the corners and using icons to identify what the issue is.

   **Problems**

   1. The icons either disruptively cover up dense content or are too small to be distinctly identifiable.
   2. Large chunks of text or images with issues can be difficult to identify if the corners are too far apart.
4. Creating diagonal watermarks for the issue across the entire container

   **Problems**

   1. The text was too light and thin, making it hard to read the watermark on top of the real text and impossible on some backgrounds
   2. The text was too dark, covering up the real text and confusing both the OCR and the reader.

## Question

I am looking for advice for

1. A solution that isn't problematic
2. Examples of other contexts with automated markup of content whose spacing and positioning isn't controlled that I can learn from.

Comment: why not go for a hybrid approach, have a button in the bottom right that says 'analyse', when you click this it takes a screen shot and highlights problems over a static image. Then when a user is done with the issues they can return to navigation. Otherwise you are going to run into problems with things like drop downs etc. By creating a fast toggle it won't impact user experience. You could then save the scroll position (if the app scrolls) and page state to create a full page analysis (by stitching together the screen shots). This also lets you mark things as non-issues as you go.

Comment: That approach is what I've seen the other apps do, but I am trying to have my app "always running in the background" so it always provides feedback instead of having to opt in which would raise the barrier to entry.

Comment: your problem is overlaying, so capture actions as you go and overlay afterwards, you could have an alert in the bottom right of the page that shows when there is a problem. You will struggle to capture the screen, overlay something and not interfere with the capture within other apps. You can identify problems on the fly and then replay with overlay to show what issue was found. This would be a lot better as if the app has any movement you will end up with overlays that are impossible to click. I might be wrong but trying to do it live seems messy and doing it 'nearly live' seems cleaner. GL!